# Display placeholder text in empty sortable with jQuery UI

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

Is there a proper non-hacky way to add a placeholder text in an empty sortable? I don't mean the placeholder white-space that gets displayed when you drag an item over the sortabel. I mean a text like "Drop items here." that is only displayed when the list is empty.

I tried to display my own placeholder element, but I fail to properly update it's visibility, because jQuery UI does not send me any over or out events when I drag a connected draggable into the sortable.

Edit: Example code: http://jsfiddle.net/RRnD8/

For some reason in this example code the `over` event is fired. `out` is still not. But in the real code I can use `change` instead of `over`.

Edit 2: Hmm, the `out` event *is* triggered. But it is triggered before the dragged element is removed from the sortable. I fixed this via:

```
e.sortable({out: function () {
    setTimeout(realOutHandler.bind(this), 0);
}});
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: you should drop some example javascript into this ticket. would make it much easier to answer your question.

Comment: @NicholasDiPiazza I added a link to a jsfiddle. But of course it does not behave exactly like what I have in the real code.
Anyway, I don't want to ask "what is my bug here", I want to ask: is there a best practice for displaying an placeholder text in an empty sortable?

Comment: OK Understood. The code example helps clarify your question. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Use the `over` event to hide the placeholder text, the `out` event to show it, and the `stop` method to remove it.

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    revert: true,
    over: function() {
        $('.placeholder').hide();
    },
    out: function() {
        $('.placeholder').show();
    },
    stop: function() {
        $('.placeholder').remove();
    }
});
$("#draggable").draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#sortable",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
});
```

**Live Example** - http://jsfiddle.net/JfGxy/2/

Comment: Yeah, for some reason it never behaves like the minimal example in the real code. Anyway, I managed to patch something together (as I said, using out+setTimeout).

Comment: Where does .placeholder come from?

Comment: How would you hide the placeholder if when you load the page some elements are already saved in the list?

Answer (score 1):

SASS way:

```
#sortable
   &:empty {
      padding: 0;
      min-height: 50px;
      z-index: 999;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      margin-right: 25px;
      border: 4px dashed #CCC;
      background-color: #F5F5F5;

      &:after {
        color: #888;
        content: "Drop items here";
        display: block;
        min-height: inherit;
        line-height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 700;
   }
}
```